Chameleon template not substituting python variables
I have the following snippet in a template:
<div tal:repeat="ag age_groups" tal:omit-tag="True">
   <input name="age_group" type="radio" id="${ag.name}" value="${ag.name}" ${ag.checked} >
   <label for="${ag.name}">${ag.name}</label>
</div>

In the Python code, I have a class defined as:
class AgeGroupInfo:
    def __init__(self, name: str, checked: str):
       self.name = name
       self.checked = checked

The view dictionary contains a list of AgeGroupInfo Objects (not precise python syntax, but you can see the values for 'name' and 'checked')
:
[('Preschool', ' '), ('Child', ' '), ('Teen', ' '), ('Adult', 'checked')]

The template gets processed into a web page with this source:
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Age Group:</legend>
                    <input name="age_group" type="radio" id="${ag.name}" value="${ag.name}"   >
                    <label for="Preschool">Preschool</label>
                    <input name="age_group" type="radio" id="${ag.name}" value="${ag.name}"   >
                    <label for="Child">Child</label>
                    <input name="age_group" type="radio" id="${ag.name}" value="${ag.name}"   >
                    <label for="Teen">Teen</label>
                    <input name="age_group" type="radio" id="${ag.name}" value="${ag.name}" checked >
                    <label for="Adult">Adult</label>
                
            </fieldset>

In some cases, the ${ag.name} gets properly substituted (in the "label" HTML statements), but in others it does not. The one use of ${ag.checked} does get properly substituted.
Any hint as to why the substitution works in some cases but not in others?
